# MojoExecutionException: Some Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed

Tags: java, maven, mojo

When I execute command `./mvnw -Pprod,swagger,webpack clean package -X`

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M1:enforce (enforce-versions) on project --: Some Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M1:enforce (enforce-versions) on project --: Some Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed.
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:39)
        at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:122)
        at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main(MavenWrapperMain.java:50)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Some Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed.
        at org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.EnforceMojo.execute(EnforceMojo.java:243)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 27 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

This link http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException was not useful for me. Could you please suggest some way to figure out from this problem.

Comment: Read `Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed.` ...

Comment: @khmarbaise Hi, yes it obvious. But I can find only this useful info [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Comment: Could you post all the stacktrace?

Comment: Read the output and remove the `-X` cause that does not help..there is a line in the output "Rule ..." ...

Comment: @khmarbaise I updated question and now part of stack trace built with ```-e``` instead ```-X```

Comment: why aren't you using mvn command? also, you are running prod profile for the product; have you tested if other profiles are running fine?

Comment: @PrateekJain very good question. I use this command because it's a part of CI/CD script. Now, I tried to reproduce error from CI/CD.

Comment: I repeat my comment from the beginning read the log above the exception/error message there is line `Rule ..`...

Comment: @khmarbaise yes you are absolutely correct that need read the log. But they haven't any specific messages, which mentioned in the end. But  logs earlier  mentioned  that I use wrong java version.

Comment: @dos4dev you didn't answered if other profiles are running fine and it is only prod profile giving issue or actual build is in bother?

Comment: @PrateekJain I added my answer, thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

As a [khmarbaise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296328/khmarbaise) mentioned need to look above the log. It difficult to add whole list of log to the question, to give all info about problem. But my problem was with version of java in my local machine. [prateek-jain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2853439/prateek-jain) this problem not related for profiles.